# Rust Lifetimes in Higher Order Functions

Tags: rust, lifetime, higher-order-functions

I have a map: `HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>>` and I'm trying to create a reverse lookup map `HashMap<&str, &str>` which refers from each of the element in the original vector to the original key.

E.g. map like below

```
{
  "k": vec!["a", "b"]
}
```

would be transformed into

```
{
  "a": "k",
  "b": "k",
}
```

It works perfectly fine when I do that with:

```
    let substitutes: HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>> = vec![("a", vec!["b", "c"])].into_iter().collect();
    
    // Below works fine
    let mut reversed: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
    for (&k, v) in substitutes.iter() {
        for vv in v.iter() {
            reversed.insert(vv, k);
        }
    }
```

However it doesn't work if I try to do that with a Higher Order Functions:

```
    // Below doesn't work
    let reversed_2: HashMap<&str, &str> = substitutes
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|(&k, v)| v.iter().map(|&vv| (vv, k)))
        .collect();
```

And gives the following errors:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `k`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:18:42
   |
18 |         .flat_map(|(&k, v)| v.iter().map(|&vv| (vv, k)))
   |                                          ^^^^^      - `k` is borrowed here
   |                                          |
   |                                          may outlive borrowed value `k`
   |
note: closure is returned here
  --> src/main.rs:18:29
   |
18 |         .flat_map(|(&k, v)| v.iter().map(|&vv| (vv, k)))
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `k` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
18 |         .flat_map(|(&k, v)| v.iter().map(move |&vv| (vv, k)))
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

I am trying to wrap my head around how `vv` might outlive `k` given that it's in the same scope under `flat_map`.

Would be really helpful to get more information why my HOF approach fails.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be19ee6d71025d6ca6d8ff039206791a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the compiler help was exactly right: you need to add `move` on the inner closure.

```rust
let reversed_2: HashMap<&str, &str> = substitutes
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|(&k, v)| v.iter().map(move |&vv| (vv, k)))
    .collect();
```

[Rust Playgroud](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=53c9cd7bd99c8f88f733ef8c5a4c4832)

When you make an anonymous function that uses variables from the surrounding scope, the inline function (called a [closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html)) needs access to those variables. By default, it takes a reference to them, leaving them available in the enclosing scope. However, in this case, the closure takes a reference to `k` and returns it, which means that it could escape the enclosing scope.

```rust
.flat_map(|(&k, v)| {
    // k is only valid in this anonymous function

    // a reference to k is returned out of map and also out of flat_map
    // (Note: no move)
    v.iter().map(|&vv| (vv, k))

    // the anonymous function ends, all references to k need to have ended
})

// A reference to k has been returned, even though k's lifetime has ended
// Compiler error!
```

When you switch to a `move` closure, rather than taking to references to things in the enclosing environment, you take ownership of the things themselves. This lets you return `k` rather than a reference to `k`, sidestepping the issue.

```rust
.flat_map(|(&k, v)| {
    // k is only valid in this anonymous function

    // k is moved out of the enclosing function and into the inner function
    // Because it owns k, it can return it
    // (Note: uses move)
    v.iter().map(move |&vv| (vv, k))

    // k has been moved out of this environment, so its lifetime does not end here
})

// k has been returned and is still alive
```

Comment: Does this means that I'm actually creating a copy of `k` from the original map?

Comment: Also, thank you a lot [ddulaney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3404377/ddulaney) ! I have tried adding `move` before but I was still at the previous version of my code```.flat_map(|(&k, &v| v.iter().map(move |&vv| (vv, k)))``` [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e5d4b5447d1b425b22d45e9edc018a4d) and thus it was resulting in different kind of errors. It all works fine now!

Comment: Glad to hear it works! `move` doesn't copy `k`, it moves it which is generally a very efficient operation (in this case, I believe it's a no-op, though I haven't verified and that's not a guarantee).